# pygame.display.update() doesn't work in a loop

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a simple game. When i draw something in a loop it draws it for less than a second. This is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import*

pygame.init()
FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 750))
BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')

while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                "do something"

            else:
                posx, posy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    if posx == 500 and posy == 500:
                        DISPLAYSURF.fill((40, 40, 40))
                        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, (40, 40, 40), (posx, posy, 50, 20))

        pygame.display.update()
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You only update the display when there *are* events that *aren't* `MOUSEMOTION` - why?! Remember that indentation is important in Python...

Comment: @jonrsharpe this is for a map in my game, when events are `MOUSEMOTION` i want to move the map, when the events are `MOUSEBUTTONUP` i want to start a level but to test I've used the `draw()` function

Comment: Yes, but the point is that **you want to update the display whatever happens!**

Comment: @svs Hint: Remove 16 spaces from the last line.

Comment: @muddyfish so? (see edit)

Comment: yes, thanks, but now when i move my mouse after i started my level i go back to my map but i think i can fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only updating the display if the mouse is at 500,500, and the event MOUSEBUTTONUP is triggered. I would change it to:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import*

pygame.init()
FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 750))
BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            "do something"

        else:
            posx, posy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if posx == 500 and posy == 500:
                    DISPLAYSURF.fill((40, 40, 40))
                    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, (40, 40, 40), (posx, posy, 50, 20))

    pygame.display.update()
```